# Accesing an IIS hosted website in Ubuntu under VMWare

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, vmware, virtualization

So as the question goes, I have hosted a ASP.NET and C# website in IIS in my Windows 7 Ultimate OS. Not I need to be able to access the same site from ubuntu which is actually a virtualized OS running under VMWare.

I am able to access the website in my Windows 7 pc without any problems. But inside the Ununtu there seems no way to do the same.

I searched many forums for the same, no luck! Disabled the Firewall(Actually) to make sure no security issues arise but still not able to do the required thing.

This is the error :

```
Server not found
          Firefox can't find the server at www.google.com.

      Check the address for typing errors such as
        ww.example.com instead of
        www.example.com
      If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
        connection.
      If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
        that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

the vm can access the host machine? if you use `NAT` connection mode  seems cannot communicate with the host. Try `Bridge` instead?

Comment: I am not a networks guy... Can u plz explain me how to do the same?

Comment: @DevonSmith if the vm can ping the host machine successful?

Comment: try this http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_changing_bridged_windows.html

Comment: Nopes... Destination Host Unreachable. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Check if the connection type is `NAT` or `Bridge`. Change it to `Bridge`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9780/discussion-between-llj098-and-devon-smith)